# How can I scale a UV Island within a precise border in my low-res texture?

Tags: uv, snapping, scale

I'm having a bit of a specific issue that I can't seem to find an answer to.

For context, I'm trying to apply a low-res pixel texture to a blocky (Minecraft) character model. However, this model has a high amount of subdivisions around the limb joints, i.e. the elbows and knees, to allow for smooth bending.

The result is that my arm's UV island looks like this:

[image: I need the arm's texture UV island to align with the arm texture perfectly, placing by hand like this is isn't perfect]

The subdivisions around the joint are smaller in size than the size of 1x1 pixel. This means that **if I use Snap to Pixels on this island, these tiny subdivisions become squished/distorted.**

Is it possible to have this island fit the arm texture perfectly, without the subdivisions losing their original shape and proportions?

Any help would highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

here is an idea, but just to warn you, I am taking advantage of the "ANY help would be highly appreciated."  Hope it is worth it :)

I have a simple repeating texture:

[image: texture]

Now I have created an example mesh like your arm:
[image: mesh]

What I have done to the corner edges is I have selected them, hit ctrl-E, and select "Mark Seam."  Then I selected the entire mesh and hit "u", and then I selected from the drop-down, "unwrap."
I then applied the texture to the arm.  Now select the entire mesh, go to the UV image editor, select all of the mesh in the UV editor window, and scale it to the appropriate size.

The texture will not be aligned on each side, however.  I fixed this by aligning it manually.  This is how: you select one whole side at a time, move over to the UV image editor, select the mesh, and move it on the x and y axis.  This will change the position that the texture is on the mesh, as shown below.  Make sure, when moving the texture, that you are moving the mesh on the UV image editor window, and NOT on the 3D view window.
[image: aligningTexture]

This is a lot more manual work, and I hope that I did not lose you.  If I did, please say so, and I will edit this post.  Here is the result you will get:

[image: result]

If this doesn't exactly apply to your problem, then don't feel bad to clue me in, and I will try to help.

Comment: Hey RBlong2us, thanks so much for the response! Although the effect you achieve is very close to what I need, unfortunately I think it's not quite the solution I'm looking for :( This way, even though the unwrap is lined up, you still need to scale it down manually, and as a result of that, you see that the pixels are not 100% flush with the face of the cube's edges. Essentially, my subdivisions arent pixel perfectly cut, but I just care about the scale of the UV island being pixel perfect. Any way to do this without distorting all the vertices(since my subdivisions/faces arent pixel perfect)?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for responding.  I think I might be able to figure out an idea.  Do you think you could upload your .blend file?  I'd like to take a crack at it!  If I figure out a solution, I can show you how I did it.

Comment: I'm curious: would you be willing to modify the texture to fix the problem?

Comment: OK, I need you to explain how the Snap to Pixels works.

Comment: 1) I've made a finished test/placeholder texture so you can fiddle with it if you want, thanks so much for trying to help out with this, you're a legend. How do I send it to you? 2) It depends on how it would have to be changed, but I think so! 3) Snap to pixels is a function which, as the name implies, makes all the points making up a UV island snap to the corner of a pixel. Essentially this means that if the texture you supply to place the UV islands on is very low resolution, you can move the island on a grid the size of the pixels!

Comment: Could you upload the texture as a link?

Comment: https://imgur.com/AWrAQsU And here's also the .blend, so you can apply it to the model! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q5T3Pi1Vuuok51c1NqyQ3RQbq3m7himB/view?usp=sharing Let me know if there are any issues!

Comment: OK, I've got one problem at the moment;  i'm still using Blender 2.79, so when I download the file, I get a warning saying that it was "written with newer Blender binary (280.0)  expect loss of data!"  Can you copy the mesh and paste it in Blender 2.79?  If you no longer have 2.79 on your computer, don't worry about it.

Comment: Is there a reason you need all that subdivision, besides near the joints?  If not, I might have a suggestion.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wq5319MHcSHNKS6u3Ha38oTDuHYD0DR7/view?usp=sharing Sorry about the late reply! Here's a 2.79 exported version just in case. All the subdivisions were made by the modeller and animator on our team, I believe they're necessary for more flexible cartoony animation, even on parts like the head and torso

Comment: Hey, I just looked at your new .blend file (Thanks for sending it!), and except for the UV unwrapping at the bottom of the character and between the legs, it looks great.  Could you clarify the problem?  Is the unwrapping between the legs and the bottom the problem?

Comment: Did you figure out the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could upscale the texture- if you're not using it in-game, it won't matter if you 2x or 3x it, so that 1x1 pixel becomes 2x2 or something larger